# If a subset excludes 0, can the set as whole still be compact.

Tags: general-topology

I work in econometrics and so far, I have not yet dealt with topology much, so as such as I pose you the following question. Typically, as a step to prove consistency, what is done is that compactness of the parameter space $\phi$ is simply assumed. However, now the objective function depends on a quotient of a subset of parameters $\gamma ⊂ \phi$, so that zero must excluded from this subset:

So lets say: $$\gamma ⊂ \phi ⊂ R^{p}$$  and: $$\gamma \;\;excludes\;\;  {0}$$

Can $\gamma $ and thus $\phi$ be compact still?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

B.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a subset of a compact set to be compact, the subset must be closed.  If $\gamma\setminus\{0\}$ is still closed under whatever topology you're using, then the set is indeed compact.

Comment: Jon, the problem I have is if the range of the set [a:b] is closed and bounded but includes zero, mainly.

Comment: If you're doing things in $\mathbb R$ and $0\in[a,b]$ then you're in trouble since you're left with $[a,0)\cup (0,b]$.  If you can restrict $\gamma$ further by eliminating a closed interval containing $0$, say $[0-\varepsilon,0+\varepsilon]$ for some small $\varepsilon>0$, then you're OK.